# How to format value in onPreferenceChangeListener before saving?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I have an `EditTextPreference` in my `PreferenceScreen` in the field i have to save the user have to input a valid URL and as that url will be used for retrofit calls i have to format it properly.

So i've created a `onPreferenceChangeListener` where initially i check if the url insert is valid and then i'm formatting it.

The issue is that once the user press *ok* the formatted value is not saved, no value is saved at all.

Here is my listener:

```
private fun String.formatURL(): String {
    var url = this

    if (!this.startsWith("http")) {
        url = "http://$url"
    }

    if (!url.endsWith("/")) {
        url = "$url/"
    }

    return url
}

editPref?.onPreferenceChangeListener =
    Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
        val url = newValue.toString()
        if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()) {
            preference.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(preference.key, url.formatURL())
            false
        } else {
            customSnack(requireView(), "URL del server non valido!", true)
            false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that `OnPreferenceChangeListener` return `true`/`false` if value can be stored or not. you are returning `false` even whe  URL matches pattern. you should return `true` then

```
    if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()) {
        preference.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(preference.key, url.formatURL())
        true // proper URL, storing, handled
    } else {
        customSnack(requireView(), "URL del server non valido!", true)
        false
    }
```

Comment: if i return true the saved value will be newValue and not the formatted one

Comment: thats because `preference.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(preference.key, url.formatURL())` isn't ending with `commit()` or `apply()` method, so no value is set again. only `newValue` will be stored when returning `true`. well, it this case you prabably should return `false` in both cases, but still need `commit()`/`apply()` for storing `url.formatURL()` in prefs

Comment: just tried and even with ending `apply()` if i return true it's setting newValue, at this point i think the issue was that i missed the `apply()`, just tried even if i return false and set add the missed `apply()` it's not working

Comment: keep returning `false`, but also `commit`/`apply`. also add some `Log.i()` in this method and log your data. calling `commit`/`apply` may cause `OnPreferenceChangeListener` to be called again

Comment: yeah the correct way is to set `false` in return but the issue is that by doing to the summary set to `useSimpleSummaryProvider` is not updated